# How to check all radio boxes in a page with js code?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

This is the codes for radio box.

```
<div class="question-answer">
    <label style="margin: 10px;">
        <span class="kt-font-bolder">1</span>
        <br>
        <input name="2" type="radio" label="1" value="1">
    </label>

    <label style="margin: 10px;">
        <span class="kt-font-bolder">2</span>
        <br>
        <input name="2" type="radio" label="2" value="2">
    </label>

    <label style="margin: 10px;">
        <span class="kt-font-bolder">3</span>
        <br>
        <input name="2" type="radio" label="3" value="3">
    </label>

    <label style="margin: 10px;">
        <span class="kt-font-bolder">4</span>
        <br>
        <input name="2" type="radio" label="4" value="4">
    </label>

    <label style="margin: 10px;">
        <span class="kt-font-bolder">5</span>
        <br>
        <input name="2" type="radio" label="5" value="5">
    </label>

    <br>

    <span style="color: rgb(128, 0, 0);"></span>
</div>
```

There are almost 20 question in a page with same code. How can I check all 3 in radiobox with js code? Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: your question need more details

Comment: What you mean by all 3??

Comment: Can you please tell me, which information my question need?

Comment: "Check" as in "I would liked to find out which one has been selected", or "check" as in "I would like to select all of them at once"? (You can't do the second one btw.) Not sure why you added the "checkbox" tag tho. Did you want them instead of radio buttons? @TheDragonWarrior

Comment: Do you mean checkbox or radio? Radio is an element that represents a single choice from all available.

Comment: your desired result is confusing , since you have same name `name="2"` for all your radio buttons that means those all are in one group only on of them can be selected at a time

Answer (score -1):

You could try `document.querySelectorAll` to find the elements you want by using a css selector like `.question-answer input[type="radio"][value="3"]`. Then you can iterate over that list and set the `checked` property to `true`.

```js
const inputElementsWith3 = document.querySelectorAll('.question-answer input[type="radio"][value="3"]');
inputElementsWith3.forEach(function(radio) { radio.checked = true; });
```